# Apache camel onCompletion call back doesn't trigger after route is completed

Tags: java, apache-camel, disruptor-pattern

I have the following route setup in camel. I have posted the complete code here.
After the ProcessorTwo is invoked, i am expecting the ProcessorOnComplete to be invoked, but it is not at all triggered. What i am missing here?

```
public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("disruptor:routingChannel?concurrentConsumers=10")
            .onCompletion()
            .process(new ProcessorOnComplete())
            .end()
            .to("disruptor:processingOne?concurrentConsumers=10")
            .process(new ProcessorOne())
            .to("disruptor:processingTwo?concurrentConsumers=10")
            .process(new ProcessorTwo())
            .stop();
    }
}

public class ProcessorOne implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Procesing one");
    }
}

public class ProcessorTwo implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Procesing two");
    }
}

public class ProcessorOnComplete implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Completion Mayuran");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.addRoutes(new CamelRoute());
        camelContext.start();
        
        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        
        producerTemplate.sendBody("disruptor:routingChannel", "Message");
        
        Thread.sleep(1000*1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried without the [stop() EIP](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/stop-eip.adoc) already? This will stop the processing of the current message and therefore probably prevent the onCompletion to kick in. At this point the stop EIP is uesless either way

Comment: Yes, I have tried with a lot fo trial and error scenarios, I couldn't understand situation where the onCompletion is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

`onCompletion()` runs when I test it, provided I have consumers for the messages sent to the disruptor queues.

You'll see the behaviour you describe if the Exchange is `InOnly` and you don't have anything consuming the messages sent to `disruptor:processingOne` or `disruptor:processingTwo`

The `onCompletion` is waiting for the messages in the disruptor queues to be processed.

The processors `ProcessorOne()` and `ProcessorTwo()` are called because camel doesn't wait for a response as the exchange is InOnly.

If the Exchange is `InOut` then the route would wait for a response from the first disruptor and probably timeout after 30 seconds. So you wouldn't see your messages from the processors.

Comment: It seems that the problem occurs because of the handed over onCompletion tasks to the `disruptor:processing*` routes. And when that route is completed they don't get executed because they are route scoped and attempted to get executed in the scope of a route (`disruptor:processing`) they haven't been defined for (`disruptor:routingChannel`).